# FPGA work as bridge I2C in, out issue

Tags: fpga, i2c

I'd like to use I2C signals on the FPGA from cypress 2.0 module with i2c pins as below.
but It does not work well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkNVP.jpg)
[image]

Xilinx FPGA  <--------------------> MCU module (I2c)

```
.UCF
NET in_scl LOC = "A1";
NET in_sda LOC = "A2";

NET out_scl LOC = "C1";
NET out_sda LOC = "C2";
```

and in verilog as below, I'm implemented.

```
module top();

inout wire in_sda;
inout wire in_scl;

inout wire out_sda;
inout wire out_scl;


assign out_sda = in_sda;
assign out_scl = in_scl;



endmodule
```

Can you help me what am I missing?

Comment: Is this a redone version of an earlier question? Why does the FPGA need to be in the system at all, rather than just a wire?

Comment: @pjc50 There are a lot of reason why do this. but not this time.

Comment: @Neil_UK Everything works for some definition of *work*. How am I supposed to guess what's wrong from the statement "It does not work well"? Did it catch fire? Did it not communicate at all? Did the OP not reach the transfer speed he expected to reach?

Comment: The only way this is "unclear" is if the person complaining has as little knowledge of i2c and programmable logic as the asker.  To anyone with actual awareness, the nature and cause of the failure is immediately apparent - which is why this question received two answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In I2C communication, open collector drivers are used. The protocol depends on the level on the line being the 'wire-OR' of all the drivers.

This means that, on a local interface, a pin may be low because it is being pulled low by a remote driver, or it's being pulled low by itself.

Obviously any buffer between that sits between this interface and the remote ones must be able to distinguish **why** the line is low. If it's low because a remote is pulling it low, then it too must pull low to transmit that. If it's low because the local driver is pulling it low, then it must not, otherwise the line would get stuck low, and nothing more would happen.

Various strategies are used by vendors of (for instance) opto isolators designed for I2C. Their output pulls low to a different level to the typical local interface, and voltage sensors can distinguish which driver is pulling it low. But it's all rather flaky and depends on the local driver having 'typical' good performance.

As an I2C bus is designed to be bus connected, by far the best way to **connect** the FPGA to the bus is to implement an input and an o/c driver for each of the two pins, and connect to the two I2C bus wires. This retains the direct connection of all the items already on the bus. The minimal programming so that the FPGA does not disrupt bus traffic is to not drive the o/c outputs. To participate in bus traffic will require an I2C protocol stack in the FPGA.

A robust way to **break** the path through the FPGA is to implement two I2C stacks in the FPGA, one facing each way, to relay messages. While this may seem quite a heavy option, I2C interfaces are available as pre-written IP for FPGAs, and it eliminates the flakiness of trying to implement a dumb pass-through.

Answer (score 0):

I2C uses open-drain/collector outputs. For this reason you can't just use a typical FPGA output with a push-pull structure.

I don't know whether the FPGA you are using offers open-drain outputs.

Anyway it should be possible to mimic them using the following structure
(taken from [here](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/1651.html)):
[image]
which can be inferred using this code:

```
always @(ENABLE)
if (ENABLE)
DOUT = 1'bZ;
else
DOUT = 1'b0;
```

Of course this solution only works in one direction, but I guess you are aware of that.

Comment: Thanks but the sensor need get the i2c signals and put the i2c signal to MCU module. it means that the MCU module read and write to the sensor through FPGA. so it seems to be needed bidirectional.

Comment: Then you need to rewrite your code. Or did you expect that the input would produce an output signal?

Comment: Would you help me please? I've updated but  I think there should be something else in my code. but I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time for that. But you can find a number of implementations on the net (http://faculty.lasierra.edu/~ehwang/digitaldesign/public/projects/DE2/I2C/I2C.pdf).